Lazying loading Angular Material Modules and bundle optimization
I'm building the Angular application with version 17 and after bundling, the size exceeds the budget. With the source map explorer, the illustration shows there are multiple Angular Material modules aren't lazy-loaded such as form-field, CDK, and list. From the standalone implementation guidance, I've configure the lazy routes and the lazy components, but these Material modules are still in the initial bundles.
Since I'm using Nx, the build script is:
"build-ng-frontend": "nx build ng-frontend --configuration production --optimization --base-href ./",

Here is the script for source map generation:
"bundle-ng-frontend-report": "nx build ng-frontend --configuration production --source-map && source-map-explorer dist/apps/ng-frontend/browser/*.js",

Here is an example,
// app routes
export const APP_ROUTES: Route[] = [
  {
    path: 'topics',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./modules/help-center/routes').then((m) => m.HELP_CENTER_ROUTES),
  },
  {
    path: 'projects/:projectSlug',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./modules/project/routes').then((m) => m.PROJECT_ROUTES),
  },
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./modules/entry/routes').then((m) => m.ENTRY_ROUTES),
  },
];

// help center routes
export const HELP_CENTER_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadComponent: () =>
      import('./views/help-center-view.component').then(
        (m) => m.HelpCenterViewComponent
      ),
    children: [
      {
        path: ':name',
        loadComponent: () =>
          import('./components/main-content/main-content.component').then(
            (m) => m.MainContentComponent
          ),
      },
    ],
  },
];

Is it inevitable to have larger initial bundle size, or I misunderstand something in the build? Here is my repo if you need further investigation.


I guess the dependencies come from the toolbar. In the app component there are no Inputs filled in though so I'm not sure if the business logic rich toolbar should be used in the app component.
If yes, then I would consider using @defer with when condition to defer loading of the conditional data that are present in the toolbar.
@defer (when this.snav && this.settings && this.projects)
 // the if condition needs to be present only if
 // the `when` condition could became falsy again.
 @if (this.snav && this.settings && this.projects) {
        <mat-form-field
          appearance="outline"
          style="margin-left: 1rem; margin-top: 20px"
        >

Using @defer could also be considered even in the app-component:
@defer(on immediate) {
  <app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
} @loading {
  <div style="height: 60px (match toolbar hegiht)"></div>
}

That will load the toolbar when the application first renders. I suggest adding a transparent/colored div of the height of the toolbar as a loading placeholder that prevents content "jump".

Appreciate the help. To address the issue, I should be aware of the new @defer, when, and other related features to optimize the bundle size. I'll deal with the rest of the UI issues.

When you come up with a final solution, you could also share it as an answer here! It could be a useful "case study."

Thanks. I'll provide more context and information that AI search engine may also use it.

I appreciate the help from @kvetis, who read my repo and provided the solution. Here is the context of the application in case sometime after, there's no code or repo link to be referenced.
As mentioned, I've already configured the lazy routing, further with lazy components. However, according to the source map, there are some libraries that aren't lazy chunked. Here is the code in my app.component.ts:
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet, ToolbarComponent],
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {}

There's only one place that may cause Angular Material modules not to be lazy chunked, the <app-toolbar> component. Have a look at the code:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-toolbar',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    NgIf,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    RouterLink,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
  ],
  templateUrl: './toolbar.component.html',
  styleUrl: './toolbar.component.scss',
})
export class ToolbarComponent {
// inputs and outputs
}

According to the post's screenshot, indeed, there's a MatFormFieldModule being imported.
Therefore, the question becomes how I can utilize Angular version 17's @defer syntax, which means deferrable view, to make the toolbar lazy-loaded. After using the on immediate condition:
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet, ToolbarComponent],
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    @defer(on immediate) {
    <app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
    } @loading {
    <div style="height: 60px"></div>
    }
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {}

After another attempt of bundling, the mentioned Angular Material modules are lazy-chucked. Do let me know if there's anything unclear. I'll modify the posted answer and add more information.
